# SWT in eclipse version 4.1 add additional dialogs

Tags: eclipse, swt

I am very new to swt and im my example I am using the following code for the shell and the display:
final GridLayout layout = new GridLayout(2, false);
        parent.setLayout(layout);

I am trying to open a new ,'panel' as it is called in java, I think in swt it is a new display/dialog? when a button is pressed in the opening shell? I have looked everywhere for an example and I tried so much and cannot get it to work.
Any ideas on what I would put into my Listener?

Thanks,
Ann.

Answer (score 0):

The equivalent to JPanel is a Composite in SWT. You should consider to read  http://www.eclipse.org/swt/snippets/ for examples.

You may also check out http://www.eclipse.org/recommenders/ which might be of help when learning SWT.